# UI for Tier Pricing vs Flat Fee

Tags: input

I am working on a UI for a reservation system where a unit can either be rented on a flat fee OR per duration. For duration mode, the unit can be rented based on blocks of hours.

In the case below, the cost to rent the unit for the first 4 hours is $25. For 4 - 8 hours, the cost is $50.

The challenge is allowing user to specify a cost for infinite use. Another words, the product owner can technically enter 1,000,000 in the box I highlighted below but I'm looking for a more eloquent solution.

Any suggestion? I appreciate your time in advance...

[image: Screenshot of price input]

I have 2 versions at the moment:

[image: UI Options]

Comment: Related: [Integer input field: special case for unbounded / unlimited](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/integer-input-field-special-case-for-unbounded-unlimited/45715#45715)

Comment: Hi 3nafish. Thanks for the input. I can somehow see the relationship though I'm struggling to apply it to my scenerio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about letting the user define a minimum fee (i.e. a baseline price), and then fees above a certain usage threshold.

The last tier will automatically be the one for infinite use.

[image]

Comment: I like this one because it's understandable and removes redundant fields (maximum and minimum for the next tier). Not to mention less form validation necessary! Thanks

Comment: @dkhgh thanks for taking the time. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Less is more!

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the infinite symbol (**∞**) as default value when the field is empty.

This would be the default value when a new row is created, and it will be the value of the field if the user deletes the value he has entered...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer JEA. I have tried that before and I'm still "hoping" there's a more eloquent solution for addressing this issue. I appreciate your response.